# RxSwift - rx.tap not working

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have view controller. Inside it I have view

```
lazy var statusView: StatusView = {
       var statusView = StatusView()
        return statusView
}()
```

Inside statusView I have button

```
lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
        var button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont().regularFontOfSize(size: 20)
        return button
  }()
```

In controller I have

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupRx()
}

func setupRx() {            
        _ = statusView.backButton.rx.tap.subscribe { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            print("hello")
        }
    }
```

But when I tap to button, nothing get printed to console.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

In general nothing wrong, but there's a minor hidden trick.

You use
`backButton.rx.tap.subscribe { [weak self] in`

But you need to use
`backButton.rx.tap.subscribe { [weak self] _ in ...`

Did you notice underscore in the second version? The second version calls method

```
public func subscribe(_ on: @escaping (Event<E>) -> Void)
```

of ObservableType. In this case `on` closure to deliver an event is provided, but we just ignore incoming parameter of this closure using underscore

Comment: This works for me! Super wield that why calling it without the argument will pass the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the subscription is going out of scope as soon as `setupRx` returns.  If you add a `DisposeBag` to the view controller and add the subscription to the dispose bag, does that solve the problem?  Something like this:

```
func setupRx() {            
    statusView.backButton.rx.tap
        .subscribe { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                print("hello")
            }
        }
        .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
```

Hope that helps.